# how to print values of dictionary in a list using one line excluding the last element

Tags: python

in one of my assignment i was tasked to do this:

```
1 >>> d = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 5}
2 >>> print ________
3 ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

how to only use one line of code in line 2 of the code above without importing any other functions to get the ouput `['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']` in line 3?

i can only print out all the values of the dictionary without excluding the last element using `print(list(d.values()))` and my result is `['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 5]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: prior to python 3.7 dicts were not guaranteed ordered so the *last* value is not really a thing. for later python versions you may slice the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you want to print only string dictionary values (which in the given example will exclude the last integer value), you can use list comprehension inside the print() and check if the dictionary value is of string type:

```
print([val for val in d.values() if type(val) == str])
```

This will also work if you had a dictionary like this:

```
d = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 5, 6: 'six'}
print([val for val in d.values() if type(val) == str])
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'six']
```

Answer (score 0):

one line answer:

```
list(d.values())[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

d.values() is not subscriptable, so you need to cast it into a list.
Then you can get the entire list minus the last element

```
print (list(d.values())[:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print([v for (k,v) in d.items() if type(v) != int])
```

OUTPUT:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```